# Using networkX graph from a parent class as a variable in another class

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, networkx

I'm honestly not sure if I'm attacking this the right way, but I made a graph using `networkx` to use a map in a game that I am working on. The game works, but as of right now it does not have a location system. I created the graph object in a class and I want the class cell to inherit the graph 'G' so that I can assign it to the map variable. I finally got it to not send errors , but when I print the map variable it does not print the graph. 
How do I know if G is assigned to the map variable and is this the best way to be doing this? I am open to suggestions.

```
class Graph(BaseGameEntity):
def __index__(self):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(6,9),(9,10),(10,11),
            (11,12),(10,13),(13,14),(14,15),(15,16),(16,17),(15,18),(18,19),(19,20),
            (18,21),(21,22),(22,23),(23,24)])
    G.node[1]['building'] = 'Home'
    G.node[12]['building'] = 'Store'
    G.node[24]['building'] = 'Mine'
    G.node[8]['building'] = 'Bank'
    G.node[17]['building'] = 'Saloon'
    G.node[20]['building'] = 'Jail'
    G.node[2]['Mugger'] = 'Mean Mugger'
    G.node[7]['Path'] = 'Rocky Path'
    G.node[11]['Rock'] = 'Big Rock'
    G.node[16]['Mugger'] = 'Nice Mugger'
    G.node[23]['Path'] = 'Flooded Path'
    G.node[3]['Surprise'] = 'Money'
    G.node[4]['Rock'] = 'Small Rock'
    G.node[5]['Path'] = 'Rocky Path'
    G.node[6]['Path'] = 'Rocky Path'
    G.node[9]['Surprise'] = 'Money'
    G.node[10]['Surprise'] = 'Health'
    G.node[13]['Path'] = 'Rocky Path'
    G.node[14]['Path'] = 'Rocky Path'
    G.node[13]['Rock'] = 'Medium Rock'
    G.node[15]['Path'] = 'Rocky Path'
    G.node[18]['Surprise'] = 'Money'
    G.node[19]['Surprise'] = 'Health'
    G.node[21]['Path'] = 'Smooth Path'
    G.node[22]['Path'] = 'Rocky Path'

class Cell(Graph):
    def __init__(self, game, objects, blocked, position, coords, map, graph):
        super().__init__()
        self.objects = {}
        self.blocked = False
        self.position = (0,0)
        self.map = graph.G
        print(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, but I see several issues in your code.

First, you implement the method `__index__`, but there are very few use cases for that in practice. And even if you meant to, it must return a result, but you didn't use a `return` statement.

Assuming you returned `G`, it would not help you, because `nx.Graph` is not hashable, whereas map keys have to be hashable.

I do not see how to solve this issue, because I do not understand what you meant to do.

---

Another possibility is that you did not mean to implement `__index__` (an obscure method to change the behavior of `[]` operators) but `__init__` (the object constructor).
In that case, you would have to replace the name `__index__` by `__init__`, and make it assign `G` to `self` (eg `self.G = G` at the end of the function).